# I am trying to create a basic social media app using mern stack ann i have a specific problem on editPost method using redux toolkit createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am trying to build a basic social media app using mern stack. I fetch data asynchrosously using createAsyncThunk on redux toolkit and axios get method. Same with axios delete and findByIdAndRemove in mongoose. The problem is in findByIdAndUpdate and patch method.the content is not updating on screen. The api call is ok because it works on postman .I am doing somethign wrog in redux i think its first time trying this way

my contollers

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import PostMessage from "../models/postMessage.js";

export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const postMessages = await PostMessage.find();
    res.status(200).json(postMessages);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const post = req.body;

  const newPost = new PostMessage(post);
  try {
    await newPost.save();
    res.status(201).json(newPost);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

export const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { title, message, creator, selectedFile, tags } = req.body;

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
      return res.status(404).send("No post with that id");
    else {
      const updatedPost = {
        creator,
        title,
        message,
        tags,
        selectedFile,
        _id: id,
      };
      await PostMessage.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updatedPost, {
        new: true,
      });
      res.status(200).send(updatedPost);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
      return res.status(404).send("No post with that id");
    await PostMessage.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Post deleted succesully!" });
    // console.log(id);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

the methods

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:5000/posts";

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
export const updatePost = (id, { updatedPost }) =>
  axios.patch(`${url}/${id}`, JSON.stringify(id, updatedPost));

export const deletePost = (id) => axios.delete(`${url}/${id}`);
```

the form where i submit

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useStyles from "./styles";
import { TextField, Typography, Button, Paper } from "@mui/material";
import FileBase from "react-file-base64";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addNewPost, editPost } from "../../reducers/postsSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

//GET THE CURRENT ID

const Form = ({ currentId, setCurrentId }) => {
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
    creator: "",
    title: "",
    message: "",
    tags: "",
    selectedFile: "",
  });
  const post = useSelector((state) =>
    currentId ? state.posts.find((p) => p._id === currentId) : null
  );

  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (post) setPostData(post);
  }, [post]);

  const clear = () => {
    setCurrentId(null);
    setPostData({
      creator: "",
      title: "",
      message: "",
      tags: "",
      selectedFile: "",
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (currentId) {
      dispatch(editPost(currentId, postData));
    } else {
      dispatch(addNewPost(postData));
    }
    clear();
  };

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <form
        autoComplete="off"
        noValidate
        className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <Typography variant="h6">
          {currentId ? "Editing" : "Creating"}
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          name="creator"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Creator"
          fullWidth
          value={postData.creator}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="title"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Title"
          fullWidth
          value={postData.title}
          onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })}
        />
        <TextField
          name="message"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Message"
          fullWidth
          multiline
          rows={4}
          value={postData.message}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="tags"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Tags (coma separated)"
          fullWidth
          value={postData.tags}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value.split(",") })
          }
        />
        <div className={classes.fileInput}>
          <FileBase
            type="file"
            multiple={false}
            onDone={({ base64 }) =>
              setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })
            }
          />
        </div>
        <Button
          className={classes.buttonSubmit}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          size="small"
          onClick={clear}
          fullWidth
        >
          Clear
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

and the reducers

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import * as api from "../api";

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/fetchPosts", async () => {
  const response = await api.fetchPosts();
  return response.data;
});

export const editPost = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/editPost",
  async (id, updatedPost) => {
    const response = await api.updatePost(id, updatedPost);
    console.log({ updatedPost });

    return response.data;
  }
);
export const addNewPost = createAsyncThunk("posts/addNewPost", async (post) => {
  const response = await api.createPost(post);
  return response.data;
});

export const deleteSinglePost = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/deletePost",
  async (id) => {
    const response = await api.deletePost(id);
    return response.data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  status: "idle",
  error: null,
};
export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchPosts.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
        state.posts = action.payload;
      })

      .addCase(fetchPosts.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(addNewPost.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(addNewPost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
        state.posts.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(addNewPost.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(editPost.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(editPost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";

        state.posts = state.posts.map((post) =>
          post._id === action.payload._id ? post : post
        );

        console.log(state.posts);
      })

      .addCase(editPost.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(deleteSinglePost.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(deleteSinglePost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
        const index = state.posts.findIndex(
          (post) => post._id !== action.payload
        );
        state.posts.splice(!index, 1);
      })
      .addCase(deleteSinglePost.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

// export const { addNewPost, createNewPost } = postsSlice.actions;

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

maybe the problem is in my extra reducer editPost or when returnig the data on api call